# I have an 8 gallon compressor can I use for a small project or should I use an airless sprayer?

Tags: painting, furniture, repainting, spraypainting, air-compressor

I have an 8 gallon compressor (3 cfm @ 40psi) and a small dresser to paint. Will this suffice or should I go with an airless sprayer?
Thanks!

Comment: What type of sprayer? There are small “detail” sprayers that would work great, smaller than a big body gun and larger than a pen stripe gun. I have found airless do better on large jobs little ones tend to clog and no matter how well you clean them they are done in 1 or 2 jobs,,, well that’s my experience. This is kind of a opinion question and will probably be closed if you re word to the advantages of airless vs spray with a small compressor may keep it from being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you hook it up to for a spray gun. You know the limits, shop accordingly, or use a paintbrush.

Answer (score 0):

Airless is neat technology, you can get pressure pots that allow you to power an airless spray gun from compressed air.

For a single small project spray cans are cheapest if you want airless.

If you're not worried about paint drifting just use a regular high pressure spray gun.

Paint spraying doesn't need a high volume compressor, the one you have should be fine. The requirements will be written on the box of the spray gun.

My experience with airless is that you loose a lot of paint filling the hose between the pump and the gun, which is not a big deal on a large job.  I have not tried those self-contained hand-held airless sprayers, but I imagine that they are a lot slower than a pump-based system, not that you need speed on a small job.